# how do i replace the x'th character from the right end of a string using javascript?

Tags: javascript, replace, substr

I have to find and replace the `"b"` with `"g"` in the image `src` attribute.

The initial src would be something like `"someName-b.png"`, and with JavaScript, I have to replace the `"b"` with `"g"`. But the problem is the `"someName"` can differ in length. So basically what I want to do is find the 5th character from the end of the src attribute string, and then replace the 5th char to `"g"`.

Is there a function in JavaScript that allows me to find the `x`th character from the end of a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the 5th character from end of a String: `string.charAt(string.length - 5)`.

Replace the 5th character from the end of a String: `string.substring(0, string.length -5) + 'g' + string.substring(string.length - 4)`

Comment: Thanks everyone. I have solved the issue. Well my own solution to the question was the use of "replace()"... I used it like below:
this.src.replace("-b.png", "-g.png")

(Thats a simple solution to the simple problem I had)...
But the answers you guys have come up with - awesome. Thanks for the effort everyone.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `.slice`. With negative values, this function counts from the right:

```
var a = "123456789"; // sample string

a.slice(0, -5)  // slice from begin to 5th character before end
 + "g"          // add a 'g'
 + a.slice(-4); // slice last 4 characters

// result: 1234g6789
```

Comment: Just as a point of interest, do you have any idea how slice compares to substring for performance as for this use they are very similar?

Comment: @Thor84no: There's `substr`, `substring`, `slice`. I came across this jsPerf test: http://jsperf.com/substring-extraction-methods-substring-substr-slice.

Comment: Nice resource, thanks. substring/substr win by quite a margin on my Firefox 7.0.1.

Comment: @Thor84no: I see it in the results. `slice` seems to be slower on almost all browsers. I guess it's a matter of weighing up performance and readability.

Comment: I actually prefer the readability of substring, but that may be because I'm a Java developer.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not a job for regular expressions, but hey, it works:

```
> "someName-b.png".replace(/.(.{4})$/, "g$1")
-> "someName-g.png"
```

Comment: You're right. That really isn't a job for regular expressions. You'd be better off with Richard D's suggestion.

Comment: Richard D's solution doesn't seem to work in Chrome. I'd stick with pimvdb's answer.

Comment: That's interesting. I wonder why it would be different in Chrome.

Comment: Yeah, I deleted my answer as it didn't work. I even saw it not working when I ran the fiddle but somehow didn't notice.

Comment: It's in the ECMA specification in fact: 15.5.5.2. A string's character like `str[n]` is only gettable.